# Windows exporter service is not exporting textfile_inputs

Tags: window, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have several machines(windows7,8,10,11) with windows exporter( I Use also textfile_inputs folder with a .prom file to export some variables too in order to see them using prometheus metrics).

The windows exporter is run as a service.
Everything its working as expected on windows 7,8 but on windows 10/11 its not seing the  variables found in textfile_inputs/.prom file ( even if they are the same like on Windows 7,8).

If i will run it manually via windows_exporter.exe( not as a service it will open the GUI exe  and the .prom metrics will be exported( to Prometheus).**BUT IF I WILL RUN IT  AS  SERVICE ( LIKE ON THE OTHER MACHINES IT WILL NOT SEE THEM..)**Had to mention that when firewall pop up appeared i give access to every network.

I need to run it as a service on all machines....did some one had problems in this direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by modifying the service register ( service name windows_exporter)->

imagepath -> "C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\windows_exporter.exe" --log.format logger:eventlog?name=windows_exporter --collectors.enabled cpu,logical_disk,os,service,**textfile**

By adding the textfile param
What I found quite strange is that I never had to do this in the previous versions..